# Running for loop using some other user

Tags: bash, shell, sudo

I am trying to execute a command using some other user. Here is my code

```
sudo -i -u someuser bash -c 'for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done'
```

I am expecting output as 1 2 3 but executed with someuser. Above code printing blank lines. I tried to add some other commands

```
sudo -i -u someuser bash -c 'for i in 1 2 3; do ls; done'
somefile1.txt somefile2.txt
somefile1.txt somefile2.txt
somefile1.txt somefile2.txt
```

If I try loop with the current user it gives expected output

```
for i in 1 2 3; do echo $i; done
1
2
3
```

Looks like bash is unable to resolve variable $i inside for loop. I tried escape character `\` but not helping.

Comment: Try adding `-x` to the command line.  That may reveal something useful.

Comment: Why are you using `sudo -i` with `bash -c`? Starting a login shell throws quite a substantial set of variables into play.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't working very well right now so I can't write a full answer. Short answer: Remove `-i`. `sudo` doesn't escape `$` properly when it invokes a login shell, so `$i` ends up being evaluated by the login shell (where it is unset) instead of the `bash` shell.

Comment: Digging into this has been dismaying. I _thought_ that `sudo` still had the same behavior it had before bug #413 was "fixed", wherein it would pass content through to `sh -c` unmodified other than concatenating strings together (as `ssh` also does when passed multiple distinct arguments rather than a single command line); alas, it's much more... interesting... than that now.

Answer (score 3):

#### TL;DR: Don't use `sudo -i` with `bash -c`

The usual way to use `sudo -i` is without any arguments, in which case it simply starts an interactive login shell.

If you *really must* have a login shell for some reason (which isn't good practice for running scripts), it's much saner to simply add the extra arguments needed to make your shell a login shell *to the `bash` command itself*, and keep `sudo` out of the business of changing the arguments you pass it:

```
sudo -u someuser bash -lic 'for i in 1 2 3; do echo "$i"; done'
```

...or...

```
sudo -u someuser -i <<'EOF'
for i in 1 2 3; do echo "$i"; done
EOF
```

---

#### The Gory Details

When you use `sudo -i` *with* arguments, it rewrites the argument list given to concatenate the arguments together into a single command that can be put into the argument after `-c`, so you get something like `{"sh", "-c", "bash -c ..."}`. In concatenating arguments together, sudo uses the logic from [`parse_args` handling for `MODE_LOGIN_SHELL`](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/blob/5ea0bf4ee2960c5cc919659b9bf1183edece9bd5/src/parse_args.c#L617-L667), adding an escape character before all characters that are not alphanumeric, `_`, `-` or `$`; keeping `$` out of this list was introduced in [commitish 6484574f](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/commit/6484574f9ff1a2097554e6511573ec7401063720), tagged as a fix for [bug #564](https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=564) (which was introduced by the fix to [bug #413](https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=413) -- personally, I think we would all be better off if bug 413 had been left in place rather than making any attempt to fix it).

See also [`sh -c` does not expand positional parameters if I run it from `sudo --login`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535925/sh-c-does-not-expand-positional-parameters-if-i-run-it-from-sudo-login) over at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

---

Since this behavior was deliberately put in place in 2013, I doubt there's any fixing it at this point -- any change to `sudo`'s escaping behavior has the potential to modify the security properties of existing scripts.

Comment: Worth a forward or link to the bash maintainers list. (so maybe one of the keen and penetrating minds over there can devise a more acceptable solution)